# How could I integrate patch into a c++ library header which is not under my control?

Tags: c++, header-files, backport

I use boost::log and I got stuck with a problem: there's an error in the library and it prevents my code from compiling (event unit test of later versions of Boost do not, so it is NOT a problem of my code). The error in this library was fixed after the release and there is a patch. In order to make things work I have to manually apply this patch onto my system libraries.

Now, suppose I have a number of systems where it is compiled (using CMake) and there are some developers working on it. How to backport this patch so that it would be incorporated into the build process?

- BOOST API v-1.54
- The header in question : https://github.com/boostorg/log/blame/master/include/boost/log/utility/setup/settings.hpp
- The patch in question : https://github.com/boostorg/log/commit/b0ddcbce917b9292c97003ff392994a4f99c9b4a

Comment: so you are asking if there is a way to apply the patch automatically by the build system without telling each dev to apply the patch manually ?

Comment: @Raxvan There's a way to apply patch automatically to the library which I manage. But Boost is something which is commonly installed into system paths. So I can not do it directly during the pre-build phase.

Comment: I see, there is not way i know to apply it like that, you can only move boost files to some place where you can make changes.

Comment: In some senses I will internalize the Boost into the project? This will require to reconfigure the build an change calls to the linker.